# Can not write to NFS unless chmod 777

Tags: nfs

I just followed the following tutorial

https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-nfs-server-and-client-on-debian/

My exports file looks like

```
/storage/nfs/   192.168.2.13(rw,no_root_squash,async)
```

From what I understand, with rw, and no_root_squash, I should be able to write to the nfs from the client using my normal user, and all the files that my normal user writes will become owned by nobody:nogroup however, that does not seem to be the case, and I can only write to that directory if it is chmod 777 and the files are owned by my client normal user...

How can I get the files the client writes to that directory to be owned by nobody:nogroup and be able to write to that directory without it being chmod 777

Comment: Did you restart the nfs client or the server after making the modifications?

Comment: `no_root_squash` only controls whether NFS access by root, i.e. UID 0, is "squashed" to the nfsnobody account. It doesn't affect any other accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nfs checks access permission against user id's . the UID of the user on your local machine needs to match the UID of the owner of the files you are trying to access on the server.